# How can chromatin state be measured?

Tags: chromosome, epigenetics, rna-sequencing, chromatin

I have some RNA-Seq data and I'd like to align it to the physical genome and see which sections of chromatin are geometrically open and being transcribed.  The data are already sequence-aligned, and every Google search I do for tools that might help ends up sending me down a rabbit hole.  What computational tools have helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting out with RNA data is great, since you already have fully spliced entities, despite  being in a different **dynamic** regime.

As the chromatin landscape itself is dynamic and High throughput data exploration has only begun in the last decade, consider the following tools and results with care...

You may find the following **tools helpful**:

- [Archalign](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mjbuck/ArchAlign.html.) , [Publication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21182771) (didn't work well during my day of trials)
- Ensembl chromatin-state map data (See the [database layout](http://regulatorygenomics.upf.edu/Data/DGCR8/README), [Regulatory Build](http://ensembl.murdoch.edu.au/info/docs/funcgen/index.html), and the lincRNA
  genes in the web-interface of the Ensembl databases)
- [HaploReg](http://compbio.mit.edu/HaploReg), [Publication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3245002/) (the most recent)